# How to detect the first occurrence of palindrome

Tags: algorithm, palindrome

Suppose you are reading from a character stream, the function should return when you have read the first occurrence of palindrome.

The length of the palindrome should be **even number**.

The requirement of the time complexity is O(N).

Example:

- 1st character: 4
- 2nd character: 1
- 3rd character: 3
- 4th character: 3
- 5th character: 1
- 6th character: 4, return

Comment: What do you mean by first occurrence?

Comment: Does it have to be more then one char? "read first char, return". Does it have to use the entire string? ie, "4,1,3,3" return cause "3,3" is a palindrome.

Comment: You could read my example, when the input stream is 413314. It should stop when it reads the 6th character since 413314 is a palindrome while 4, 41, 413, 4133, 41331 are not.

Comment: @jb. yes, it has to be the entire string

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the first character of the palindrome is the first letter from the input stream? Or can the palindrome start at any location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approximate solution that should be running in linear time O(n) in most cases is to use rolling hash.

You keep track of the hash of the string and its reverse. Every time you read a new character, you could update the two hash values in O(1). Then you compare the two hashes, if they are equal, then you compare the string and its reserve. If this is also equal, exits and you got a palindrome.

For example one very simple rolling hash function is hash(ck c(k-1).. c0) = (p^k*ck + p^(k - 1) * c(k - 1) + ... + c0) mod m where p is an odd prime.

So start with:

```
p = 17 // or your lucky prime number
m = 10^9 // ...
hash = 0
hash_rev = 0
str = ''
str_rev = ''
p_pow = 1    

while True
    read c
    append c to str
    prepend c to str_rev
    hash = (hash * p + c) mod m
    hash_rev = (hash_rev + p_pow * c) mod m
    p_pow = p_pow * p
    if hash == hash_rev
         if str == str_rev
             found str to be the first palindrome
```

To make it even faster, you can decleare your hash and hash_rev to be 32 bit integer and pick m = 2^32. Then you can ignore the (mod m) operation.

Comment: what if the first palindrome doesn't start with the stream start? Imagine that the first palindrome begins N characters into the stream - wouldn't you need an array of hashes, each starting at a different point, and you'd have to scan your hashes for each possible starting point of a palindromic string?

Comment: The author of this question says that the palindrome needs to be the entire string, isn't it? I may be wrong though.

Answer (score 3):

Return when you read the first character, that's a one-letter palindrome.

Comment: Just update my question to that the length of the palindrome should be even number.

Comment: An empty string is also a palindrome, and 0 is even, with this approach you don't even need to read the first chracter.

Comment: @KanWu, what if the string is 2231322 - it would then return after 22. Is this ok?

Comment: @BillCheatham it should be asked in comments to question. And yes, it should return after 22.

Comment: @kilotaras, I was trying to clarify Kan Wu's comment given here, and to understand if a trivial solution such as given in this answer would still be acceptable under the new constraint.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a slight modification of [Manacher's Algorithm](http://tristan-interview.blogspot.com/2011/11/longest-palindrome-substring-manachers.html). It allows you to find all palindromes in a string in linear time. The thing about algorithm it, that it actually proceeds from left, to right, "using" new chars when needed. The modification needed, is that you need to read new character, only when you try to access it.
Stop, if you found palindrome, that goes all way back to the beginning of the stream.

Comment: i read the manacher's algorithm on this [page](http://www.leetcode.com/2011/11/longest-palindromic-substring-part-ii.html)  
but i am not sure how manacher's algorithm to be fit into this problem  
since it has to update the "right" pointer when calculate the "P[i]", and it need to know what the character is before read it.

Answer (score 0):

This (untested C#) code will do it, but I think it might be O(n^2). Can anyone confirm/deny that please?

```
main()
{
    string str = "";
    char c1;
    char c2;

    while(true)
    {
        //has to be even, always get two chars at a time
        c1 = GetCharFromStream();
        c2 = GetCharFromStream();
        str += c1 + c2;
        if(isPalindrome(str))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            return;
        }
    }
}

bool isPalindrome(string str)
{
    if (str.Length % 2 != 0)
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("str");

    int first = 0;
    int last = str.Length - 1;

    while(first <= last)
    {
        if(str[first] != str[last])
            return false;

        first++;
        last--;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: of course its O(n^2). for each character read you go over the string to determine if its a palindrome.

Comment: @WeaselFox, yep, that's what I was thinking. My Big O-fu is still weak.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Hashset?

lets say the input stream is `1221`.

```
Hashset = empty;

if(hashset does not contain the inputelement)
{
   add to hashset. // 12 will be in the hashset. //413 for your example.
}

else
{
  delete from Hashset. // First deletes 2 and then 1. // First deletes 3, then 1 then 4.

  if(hashset is empty)
    return true; //Hashset is empty. return true.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take. It scans accumulated string on every new symbol *from the current middle of the string*, so it will fail fast if current string is not palindrome.

```
class PalindromeDetector {
    private static class DetectorImpl {
        final ArrayList<Character> string = new ArrayList<Character>(32);

        boolean addSymbol(char symbol) {
            string.add(symbol);
            return check();
        }

        private boolean check() {
            if (string.size() < 2)
                return false;

            int lowBound = string.size() / 2 - 1;
            int hiBound = lowBound + 1;
            while (lowBound >= 0 && string.get(lowBound) == string.get(hiBound)) {
                lowBound --; hiBound ++;
            }
            return lowBound == -1;
        }
    }

    static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        DetectorImpl detector = new DetectorImpl();
        int index = 0;
        while (index < s.length())
            if (detector.addSymbol(s.charAt(index++)))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's unit test for the code:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    assertFalse(PalindromeDetector.isPalindrome("4"));
    assertTrue(PalindromeDetector.isPalindrome("44"));

    assertFalse(PalindromeDetector.isPalindrome("4343"));
    assertTrue(PalindromeDetector.isPalindrome("4334"));

    assertFalse(PalindromeDetector.isPalindrome("41331"));
    assertTrue(PalindromeDetector.isPalindrome("413314"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since my 1st answer has `O(n^2)` time complexity, here's another, with `O(n)`, as requested.

```
class PalindromeDetector {
    private static class DetectorImpl {
        int firstHalfSum, secondHalfSum;
        int size = 0, tensPower = 1;

        boolean add(int v) {
            if (size % 2 == 1) {
                firstHalfSum = firstHalfSum + (secondHalfSum / tensPower) * tensPower;
                secondHalfSum = (secondHalfSum % tensPower) * 10 + v;
                if (firstHalfSum == secondHalfSum)
                    return true;
            } else {
                secondHalfSum = secondHalfSum * 10 + v;
            }

            size ++;
            if (size % 2 == 0)
                tensPower *= 10;

            return false;
        }
    }

    static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
        if (s == null || s.length() == 0)
            return false;

        int val = Integer.parseInt(s);
        int tensPower = s.length() == 1 ? 1 : (int) (Math.pow(10, s.length() - 1));
        DetectorImpl detector = new DetectorImpl();
        while (tensPower > 0) {
            int digit = val / tensPower;
            if (detector.add(digit))
                return true;

            val = val % tensPower;
            tensPower /= 10;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And here's unit test:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    assertFalse(PalindromeDetector.isPalindrome("4113"));
    assertTrue(PalindromeDetector.isPalindrome("3443"));
    assertTrue(PalindromeDetector.isPalindrome("473374"));
    assertTrue(PalindromeDetector.isPalindrome("413314"));
}
```

Answer assumes that input consists of decimal digits, but can be easily expanded for alphanumeric input (just assume that English alphabet + 10 digits give us numeric system over base 36).

Answer (score 0):

This solution (in Haskell) relies on the observation that an even-length palindrome contains a repeated character at its center.  As we read characters from the input stream, we test for such pairs and when one is found, we seed a new candidate answer.  For each candidate palindrome we also keep a list of "characters remaining to be matched" and as each new character is read, we match it against this list - without a match, the candidate is discarded.  When the match list is null, the solution has been found.  Note that though each candidate maintains its own match list, these are all just suffixes of the same list, so in Haskell these will all share space and collectively not take up more than O(n) space even when there are many candidates.

In the best case where there is only one paired character at the center of the answer and hence no "false positive" candidates, time complexity is O(n) - each character is examined no more than twice.  In the case of an input string with many false starts i.e. "abbbbbbbbbbbba" I am not sure of the time complexity - it's probably no longer O(n) but it is better than O(n^2) because no candidate is alive for longer than `min(k, n-k)` where `k` is the position of the center of the candidate.

```
filter_map::(a -> Maybe a)->[a]->[a]
filter_map op = foldr (maybeCons . op) []
  where maybeCons Nothing  ys = ys
        maybeCons (Just y) ys = y:ys

-- Return the first prefix of the input argument that
-- is an even-length palindrome.
prefix_palindrome::(Eq a)=>[a]->[a]
prefix_palindrome (x:xs) = search [x] [] xs
  where search seen ([]:_) _ = seen
        search (s:seen) candidates (x:xs) | x == s = search seen' (candidates' ++ [seen]) xs
                                          | otherwise = search seen' candidates' xs
          where seen' = (x:s:seen)
                candidates' = filter_map extend candidates
                              where extend (c:cs) | c == x = Just cs
                                                  | otherwise = Nothing
```